# Python project, installation only works with "pip install -e .", but not "pip install ."

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I've made my first python project and uploaded it on GitHub.

Upon installation with pip, I get different errors based on whether, from the root directory, I execute

```
pip install .
```

or

```
pip install -e .
```

I was able to recreate this error by having a project with these elements:

### Dir tree:

```
.
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── main.py
│   └── test.py
└── setup.py
```

---

### main.py:

```
import my_package.test
```

### test.py:

```
print("hello there!")
```

### setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='1.0.0',
    description='Description of my package',
    packages=find_packages(
        where="my_package"
    ),    
    install_requires=[]
)
```

---

This would, after executing

```
pip install .

python3 my_package/main.py
```

give this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./my_package/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import my_package.test
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_package'
```

---

Said error does not appear when main is called by using

```
pip install -e .

python3 my_package/main.py
```

giving back the expected "hello there!".

---

**I managed to fix the problem, understanding that the issue was having the main script inside of the package, while importing files from the package itself.**

But I still do not understand why it would work anyway when setting up the package/app in development mode...

**Question**: Why does that happen?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is a lot of information, but it might be the wrong information. "but in its place this new error comes up" How do you run the code to cause this error? What is the current working directory, what command do you use, and where is the project installed? Also, have you had this problem with any previous projects? Can you create a simpler project that has the same problem? Does the project need to use third-party libraries to encounter the problem? Please read [mre] and https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback; the materials that you have given me helped me solve my problem :) I have updated the question with a reprex and a new, clearer question.

Comment: I believe the problem is `import my_package.test`, because when executing `python3 my_package/main.py` the interpreter cannot find any module named `my_package`, 'cause it's inside the `my_package/` folder. When using `pip -e`, setuptools create only a link to the source code, so making available the package in question. I suggest you to check: [1](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#flat-layout) [2](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/quickstart.html#dependency-management) [3](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/development_mode.html)

Comment: You need to run the code as `python3 -m my_package.main`, that's all. You need to learn differences between a script and an executable module/package.